# Como evitar que se ejecute una query si falla la subida de un archivo

Tags: php, mysql

Estimados estoy realizando un sistema que genera ordenes de servicio a partir de un formulario donde se piden una serie de datos, los cuales son irrelevantes mencionar, pero si hay uno que influye que es un **input file**.

De lo mencionado anteriormente nace mi problemática, ya que si por alguna razón falla la subida del archivo, de igual forma se ejecutan las querys de INSERT y UPDATE, lo que me estaría generando una orden de servicio, pero no estaría subiéndose el archivo al servidor. O de otra forma si se sube el archivo al servidor, pero no se rebaja el stock con la query de UPDATE.

De que manera puedo evitar este conflicto, que validaciones debería realizar en el script PHP para poder ir validando una a una que se cumplan las sentencias, para así devolver un mensaje de éxito el usuario.

Adjunto como tengo estructura actualmente mi script

```
    public function Orden(){
        $con = new Conexion();
        if(!(empty($_POST['fabricante'])) and !(empty($_POST['modelo'])) and !(empty($_POST['año'])) and !(empty($_POST['motor'])) and !(empty($_POST['transmision'])) and !(empty($_POST['combustible'])) and !(empty($_POST['patente'])) and !(empty($_POST['kilometraje'])) and !(empty($_POST['ecu'])) and !(empty($_POST['herramienta'])) and !(empty($_POST['versionherramienta'])) and !(empty($_POST['informacion'])) and !(empty($_POST['servicioprincipal'])) and !(empty($_FILES['archivo'])) and ($_POST['confirmado'] == '1')){
            date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
            $idusuario = $_SESSION['idusuario'];
            $estado = "INGRESADA";
            $ruta = "../../archivos/";
            //DATOS DEL VEHICULO//
            $query_orden = $con->obtenerdatos("o.orden","(SELECT uuid_short() AS orden)o","?",['1']);
            $ordenservicio = 'SRV-'.$query_orden[0]['orden'];
            $fabricante = filter_var($_POST['fabricante'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $modelo = filter_var($_POST['modelo'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $año = filter_var($_POST['año'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $motor = filter_var($_POST['motor'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $transmision = filter_var($_POST['transmision'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $combustible = filter_var($_POST['combustible'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $patente = filter_var($_POST['patente'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $kilometraje = filter_var($_POST['kilometraje'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $ecu = filter_var($_POST['ecu'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);        
            //DATOS ARCHIVO//
            $herramienta = filter_var($_POST['herramienta'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $versionherramienta = filter_var($_POST['versionherramienta'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $informacion = filter_var($_POST['informacion'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
            $nombreoriginal = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
            $nombretemporal = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
            $ext = pathinfo($nombreoriginal, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $nombrefinal = $ruta.$nombreoriginal;
            //DATOS SERVICIO//
            $conjuntoservicio = filter_var($_POST['servicioprincipal'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $verificar_servicio = $con->obtenerdatos("*","escala_servicios","CONCAT(descripcion,' - ',valor,' Créditos') = ?",array($conjuntoservicio));
            $total_servicioprincipal = $verificar_servicio[0]['valor'];
            $servicioprincipal = $verificar_servicio[0]['descripcion'];
            $conjuntoadicionales = filter_var_array($_POST['serviciosadicionales'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $implode = implode(",",$conjuntoadicionales);
            $verificaradicionales = $con->obtenerdatos("*","servicios_adicionales","FIND_IN_SET(servicio,?)",[$implode]);
            $total_adicionales = 0;
            if(count($verificaradicionales) > 0){
                for($a = 0;$a < count($verificaradicionales); $a++){
                    $fila = $verificaradicionales[$a];
                    $total_adicionales += $fila['valor'];
                }
            }
            $totalcreditos = $total_servicioprincipal + $total_adicionales;
            $query_saldo = $con->obtenerdatos("creditos","usuarios","idusuario = ?",[$idusuario]);
            $saldoanterior = $query_saldo[0]['creditos'];
            $saldoactual = $saldoanterior - $totalcreditos;
            $datos = array($ordenservicio,$servicioprincipal,$implode,$totalcreditos,$saldoanterior,$saldoactual,$fabricante,$modelo,$año,$motor,$transmision,$combustible,$patente,$kilometraje,$ecu,$herramienta,$versionherramienta,$informacion,'archivos',$nombreoriginal,"",date("y-m-d H:i:s"),$idusuario,$estado);
            $insertar = $con->insertar("?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?","ordenes",$datos);
            $rebajar_creditos = $con->actualizar("creditos = creditos - ?","usuarios","idusuario = ?",array($totalcreditos,$idusuario));
            $subir = move_uploaded_file($nombretemporal,$nombrefinal);
            if($insertar && $rebajar_creditos && $subir){
                $HTML = ['Orden generada exitosamente',$ordenservicio];
            }else{
                $HTML = 'A ocurrido un error a la hora de generar la orden de servicio, favor intente nuevamente';
            }
        }else{
            $HTML = $this->validar();
        }       
        return $HTML;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con Ajax puedes controlar los procesos, nomás tendrías que separarlos cada uno y llamarlos de manera independiente:

```js
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function () {
  alert("success");
})
  .done(function () {
    alert("second success");
  })
  .fail(function () {
    alert("error");
  })
  .always(function () {
    alert("finished");
  });
```

Comment: Mi pregunta va más orientada al script de php, ya que si falla la subida del archivo, aún así se ejecuta la línea donde está la query que inserta los datos y la que actualiza los datos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar a meter la lógica que guarda en base de datos dentro de un if que compruebe que el archivo se sube correctamente.

Por ejemplo:

```
$subir = move_uploaded_file($nombretemporal,$nombrefinal);
if($subir){
    $insertar = $con->insertar("?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?","ordenes",$datos);
    $rebajar_creditos = $con->actualizar("creditos = creditos - ?","usuarios","idusuario = ?",array($totalcreditos,$idusuario));
    if($insertar && $rebajar_creditos){
        $HTML = ['Orden generada exitosamente',$ordenservicio];
    }else{
        $HTML = 'A ocurrido un error a la hora de generar la orden de servicio, favor intente nuevamente';
        //Aquí, como la imagen se ha subido correctamente, pero insertar o rebajar ha fallado, deberias de borrar la imagen del servidor.
        unlink($nombrefinal);
    }
}else{
    $HTML = 'Error al subir el archivo';
}
```

Esto es un ejemplo rápido, no te fies a la hora de copiarlo y pegarlo. Revisalo tu mismo y adaptalo a tu proyecto.